# Verify that the set $\{ (b-a)^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^\frac{2\pi ixj}{b-a} \}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(a,b)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

1. Let $H=L^2(a,b)$ with $a<b$. Verify that the set $\{ (b-a)^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^\frac{2\pi ixj}{b-a} \}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(a,b)$.
2. Verify also that $$\{(b_1-a_1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot \dots \cdot (b_n-a_n)^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{2\pi i(\frac{x_1j_1}{b_1-a_1}+ \dots +\frac{x_nj_n}{b_n-a_n}})$$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(R)$, where $R$ is the "rectangle" $(b_1-a_1) \times \dots \times (b_n-a_n) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

I know that the set problem is a direct result of the first since we just need to apply the first n times.

However, to show that the set is orthonormal in $L^2(a,b)$. I need to do the inner product of $-\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{2\pi ixj}{b-a}}$, and $-\frac{1}{2}e^\frac{2\pi ixn}{b-a}$. Is the inner product in $L^2(a,b)$, $\int_a^b -\frac{1}{2}e^\frac{2\pi ixj}{b-a}-\frac{1}{2}e^\frac{2\pi ixn}{b-a} \,dx$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard inner product on $L^2((a,b))$ is 
\begin{align}
\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{(a,b)}f(t)\bar{g}(t)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(t),
\end{align}
where $\bar{g}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $g$.

Taking $b=1$, $a=0$ for convenience, so that $(b-a)^{-1/2}=(b-a)=1$, your functions become $e_j=\exp(2\pi i x j)$, so the inner product you want to compute is 
\begin{align}
\langle e_n,e_m\rangle &= \int_{(a,b)}e_n(x)\bar{g}_m(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x) \\
&= \int_0^1 e^{2\pi i nx}e^{-2\pi i mx}\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x) \\
&= \int_0^1 e^{2\pi i x(n-m)}\,\mathrm{d}x,
\end{align}
for $n,m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. To show that this is an orthonormal basis, you need to show that this integral yields $\delta_{nm}$ ([Kronecker delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)), that is $\langle e_n,e_m\rangle=\delta_{nm}$. Then generalize to arbitrary $a,b$, $b>a$.

Comment: If $n=m$ then we have $\int_1^0 dx=1$. But shouldn't it be equal to 0?

Comment: If your set is [orthonormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormality#Definition), it means that $\langle x,y\rangle=1$ if $x=y$, and $\langle x,y\rangle=0$ if $x\not=y$. So for $n=m$, you are taking the inner product of a unit vector with itself, yielding 1. Edit: By the way, I think you mixed up the limits on your integral. :)

Comment: Yes I did. :) The question now is how to I show this inner product =0 if $=\langle e_n, e_m \rangle = \frac{1}{2\pi i(n-m)}(e^{2\pi in}-1}$ will never be 0. Or will it?

Comment: You need to show that it is $0$ whenever $n\not=m$, while it is $1$ if $n=m$. That is, $\langle e_n,e_m\rangle=\int_0^1 \exp(2\pi i x [n-m])\,\mathrm{d}x=1$ ($n=m$) and $=0$ ($n\not=m$). The case for $n=m$ is easy, as you already pointed out. For the $n\not=m$ case, you can for example write the integrand as $\cos(2\pi i x z)+i\sin(2\pi i x z)$, where $n-m=z\in \mathbb{Z}$ is some non-zero integer. Then see if you can integrate the real and imaginary parts by themselves. This might involve some trigonometric identies (and propably a change of variables for the arbitrary $b>a$ case).

Comment: Note that, of course, $z\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$, and not $\mathbb{Z}$ as stated in the above comment.

Comment: I did the integration and found $\frac{-icos(2\pi ixz)+sin(2\pi ixz)}{2\pi iz}$. But I don't see that it is equal to 1

Comment: You should get something like $\langle e_n,e_m\rangle=-(2\pi z)^{-1}i\exp(2\pi i z x)\big|_0^1$, with $z=n-m$. So we have four terms, two of them are sines and two are cosines, namely $\sin(2\pi z 1)-\sin(2\pi z 0)$ and $\cos(2\pi z 1)-\cos(2\pi z 0)$. The sine terms cancel trivially, $\sin(2\pi k)$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is always zero. For the cosine terms, note that $\cos(2\pi z 1)-\cos(2\pi z 0)=0$, since $\cos(2\pi k)=\cos(0)=1$. Thus, $\langle e_n, e_m\rangle=0$ if $n\not=m$. :)

Comment: Perfect thank you for all your help

Comment: No problem, friend.